# I have to click on the button twice to add a comment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a button in a form. When I click on it, the comment is supposed to appear with the email and a little avatar. My problem is I have to click on the button twice. I had some problems with options request. I am using a CORS plugin to execute the app, since the json file is in another domain. Now the request's type is POST but it takes 2 clicks to make it work.

Here's the function from the controller. In the view I just have an `input type=submit` with `ng-click` in it.

```js
$scope.envoyer_comment = function() {

    $scope.c = $scope.commentaire;
    $scope.e = $scope.email;

    var comment = {
      article_id: $scope.article.Article.id,
      titre: $scope.article.Article.titre,
      content: $scope.article.Article.content,
      commentaire: $scope.commentaire,
      email: $scope.email
    }

    if ($scope.flag == 0) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.yabiladi.com/newsapi/post.json",
        data: comment,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(res) {
          $scope.d = 0;

        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("Erreur");
        }


      })
    }
```

the part from the view including the use of the function

```html
<div ng-if="flag==0">

  <label for="field2"><span style="margin-left:18px;">Commentaire:</span><textarea ng-trim="false" ng-model="$parent.commentaire" class="textarea-field outer" ng-maxlength="3000" required>Hello</textarea></label>
  <span style="margin-right:130px;">{{3000 - text.length}} caractères restants</span>

  <br/>

  <label for="field3"><span style="margin-left:18px;">email:</span><input type="text" class="input-field outer" ng-model="$parent.email" style="width:50%" required></label>

  <br/>

  <label><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="checkbox1" style="margin-left:18px;"> 

Je souhaite recevoir un email à chaque commentaire<br/>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp sur cet article
</label>
  <br/>

  <label><span>&nbsp</span><input type="submit" data-ng-click="envoyer_comment()" value="Envoyer" style="margin-left:-20%" ng-disabled="commentaire_article.$invalid"/></label>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div ng-hide="d">
    <ion-item style="border:0px;font-size:10px;margin-left:-50px;margin-top:-30px" class="item-text-wrap">
      <div class="form-style-2-heading" style="background-color: #fbf8f7;color:black;height:47px;margin-bottom:6px;margin-top:6px">
        <div style="margin-left:-240px;padding-top:5px"><img ng-src="img/sans titre.png" height="41" width="35" style="margin-left:-85px;margin-bottom:12px" style="border:0px">
          <div style="margin-left:45px;margin-top:-50px">{{e}}</div><br/>
          <div style="margin-left:90px;margin-top:-10px"> Date:{{timeNow|date:"d/m/y à HH:mm":"UTC"}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="padding-right: 50px;margin-bottom:30px" align="left">{{c}}</div>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
  <ion-list ng-repeat="article2 in article1.comments">



    <ion-item style="border:0px;font-size:10px;margin-left:-50px;margin-top:-30px" class="item-text-wrap">
      <div class="form-style-2-heading" style="background-color: #fbf8f7;color:black;height:47px;margin-bottom:6px;margin-top:6px">
        <div style="margin-left:-240px;padding-top:5px"><img ng-src="{{article2.avatar}}" height="41" width="35" style="margin-left:-85px;margin-bottom:12px" style="border:0px">
          <div style="margin-left:45px;margin-top:-50px">{{article2.PhorumMessage.author}}</div><br/>
          <div style="margin-left:90px;margin-top:-10px"> Date:{{article2.PhorumMessage.datestamp * 1000|date:"d/m/y à HH:mm":"UTC+0100"}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="padding-right: 50px;margin-bottom:30px" align="left">{{article2.PhorumMessage.body}}</div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</div>
```

The variable `flag` is for language, the variable `d` is to show the new comment.

screenshot  from dev tools
[ss dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIuOv.png)

Comment: Can you show us a Screenshot of the Chrome Developer Tools - Network tab when you click in the button? http://imgur.com/NisJR26

Comment: Please don't appened _SOLVED_ to your title. Marking an answer as accepted is how you mark your question as solved.

Comment: except i can't accept my own answer

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows

```
<button type="button" onclick="yourfunction()">

<script>
    function yourfunction (){
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i tried your solution.didn't work.actually there's no requests fired after i used ondblclick instead of ng-click

Comment: @Rated Ace Use ng-dblClick="myfunc()"

Comment: :i tried your solution but i have to click the button more times now

Answer (score 0):

Could you give more details about the html code?

I'll assume that there is nothing changing the vlue of the "$scope.flag" variable and that you have checked if there isn't any error in the first execution.

If you can, post the code of the web page.

Comment: This is a comment.

Comment: the flags are for the language of the news(i have multiple json files for other languages).i'll update the post

Comment: Try changing 
<input type="submit"
To
<input type="button"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by trying everything and anything.I added in the request body async:false and it worked.Thanks to everyone who helped